# Tracking and displaying users current activity in django app

Tags: django, action, feed

***My App***: I have created a small blog application in django. Each blog has the following attributes. 1)title  2)body  3)image 4)upvote/downvote button  5)rate  6)comment

Any logged-in user can either upvote or downvote a particular blog,rate it giving a number between 1-5 or comment on that blog.

***My Question***: Now I want to display the activities a user performs on a blog.Say I want to display it on a different webpage  /recent_actions

Like if a user x(say) upvotes a blog y(say)  the page /recent_actions should get updated.The most recent content of the page should be like "user x upvoted blog y 2 minutes ago" 
In short I want to create a newsfeed for my blog app.

My thoughts: I am thinking to create an activity class to keep track of changes made in particular fields(say likes in blog model)

Anyone here have any explaination in detail whether i am thinking it right or is their some other better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right way.

In my project, I wrote an `Event`class which is abstract, and several other classes based on this class.

It is something like:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    is_cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ScanEvent(Event):
    # fields/methods related to scan actions only


class ReadEvent(Event):
    # fields/methods related to read actions only

class ...
```

As the Event class is abstract, no table is created in the DB, but I stay DRY in Django because I don't write `is_cancelled` attributes many times.
It works like a charm for me.

I didn't know about the django-activity-stream proposed by Aamir Adnan. Il could be good to take a look. Maybe it's overkill for you needs, maybe it's exactly what you need :)